# Running MySql script from Cmd.exe in MS Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, windows-7

I am trying to run a **MySQL** script from the **cmd.exe** command line in windows 7.

I have tried referencing MySQL by its physical path, then by enclosing its physical path in quotes, and then by creating a `MYSQL_HOME` variable, placing `MYSQL_HOME` in the windows PATH variable, and calling MySQL from the command line.  But all of these approaches are giving errors.  How can I get the simple `--init-file=...` command to run from cmd.exe?

Here is a print screen of the failed commands that I have tried:

[image]

Here are the names and values of the windows environmental variables that I set:

```
variable name        variable value
MYSQL_HOME           C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin
PATH                 ...;%MYSQL_HOME%;...
```

Here is the printscreen resulting from following Rahul's advice:

[image]

Comment: Does you PATH have %MYSQL_HOME% literally there or is it expanded to full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should quote your path using `"` instead of `'` like

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin"
```

once `cd` to the folder, run command `dir` and see if `mysql.exe` is present or not (for verification)

Again, if you have just added below environment variable, it will not take effect on the current command window. Exit and re-open the command window for it to take effect.

```
MYSQL_HOME           C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin
```

**EDIT:**

Are you sure `--init-file` option is present (or) a valid option to use. If I am not wrong, then there is no `--init-file` option present.

Try `mysql --help` or `mysql -?` and see if that option really exists or not.

**EDIT1:**

you are doing it wrongly. In this case, you should be using `mysqld.exe` instead like

```
mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

See this Mysql documents which clearly mentioned how to reset root password

[Resetting the Root Password: Windows Systems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.0/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html)

[C.5.4.1 How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: @CodeMed, I believe you have posted another question for that issue. until you are not posting same question, you are not at all littering SO. Moreover, it's always suggested to post different question in different thread. So that problems are isolated and you get better answer. please post a new question (if you haven't done so already) and mark this resolved. We will talk on that new thread and see if I can be of any help.

Comment: @CodeMed, do post the link of your new question/post here.